# How do you unminimise a java swing window?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have Java Swing application that I am developing in NetBeans.

What I want to do is: if some tries to open a new JFrame and that window is already created, bring it to the front and unminimize.  I give all the windows names when they're created (yes some are dynamic) e.g.

```
public class GUIother extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public GUIother () {
        this.setName("GUIother");
        // some other code will go here
    }
        // some other code will go here
}
```

When a user causes an action, say via a button or menu:

```
private void Click_versionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    if(!WindowExists("GUIversion")) new GUIversion().setVisible(true);
}
```

Now I have it working so far and it will bring an existing window to the front, but if its minimized it stays that way:

```
public static boolean WindowExists(String WindowName) {
    boolean exists = false;
    Window[] children = GUImain.getWindows();
    for (Window win : children) {
        if (win.getName().equals(WindowName) && win.isVisible()) {
            exists=true;
            win.toFront();
            win.???();  // unminimize
        }
    }
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Try to change its state to normal : _win.setState(Frame.NORMAL);_

Comment: I worked out what I needed to put was:                     ((JFrame)win).setState(JFrame.NORMAL);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the extend state of the frame:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
```